# jQuery giving me "undefined" echoing json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to print out "message"

JSON:

```
[{"outcome":false,"message":"This is the message"}]
```

I've tried 3 things, here are the outcomes of them...

`console.log(msg)` => `[{"outcome":false,"message":"Your account is pending beta activation"}]` (this is fine)

`var x = $.parseJSON(msg);`

`console.log(x)` gives me an object

`console.log(x.message)` gives me `undefined`

What's the correct way to access `msg.message`, if not like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an Object in an Array. Use index `0`.

```
x[0].message;
```

---

If you're anticipating more Objects in the Array, you can use `$.each` to iterate the Array.

```
$.each(x, function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.message);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your getting a json object containing an array returned, did you try:

```
console.log(x[0].message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is an Array of Object's

Instead you should  be using

```
x[0].message;
```